# sql query with offset and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

My database table contain "created_time" column.
I need to get only one record at a time based on the "created_time" column.
  (starting from least date&time)

For that i wrote the query like

```
select * from table_name order by created_time limit 1 OFFSET 1
```

if i execute the query i am getting one record which has least time in database.

I need to write the query by increasing the offset value automatically?How to write the query?

Comment: This appears to be a question about basic pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query as below, no need to mention offset.

```
select * from table_name order by created_time limit 1
```

In this you are limiting the data to one record. The OFFSET argument is used to identify the starting point to return rows from a result set.

Comment: Thanks for your response.If i execute the above query , i am getting same record every time.Which was not suitable to my problem.I need to get the record based on "created_time" column based on least time.                               means,i need to get 16th date then 17th date like that...

Comment: Ok, can u give me a quick example?

Comment: Suppose table contains records,                                                                                                                                                                                        16-10-2018  , 17-10-2018  i need to get records by date.If i execute above query i am getting first record every time. second time i need to get second record(17th date). I think the query needs offset for this scenario?

Comment: Yes for this you need offset. I will edit my answer. In which language, you have the date variables

Comment: The date variables type is ZonedDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

ASC  or DESC  by  created_time?
select * from table_name order by created_time desc limit 1